# React - Fetch Data from API and map nested JSON

Tags: reactjs, json, api

for a few days now I'm trying to solve the following problem. Of course I have researched and tried several solutions to the error message and unfortunately none of them work. I do not know what I'm doing wrong and would therefore like to ask you about it. :)

Error-Message:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Code:

```
function App() {
  const [games, setGames] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getGames();

    async function getGames() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?season=2021&league=78&date=2021-12-04",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
            "x-apisports-key": "XXX",
          },
        }
      );

      const data = await response.json();
      setGames(data.parameters);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Games</h1>
      <div className="games">
        {games.map((game, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <h2>{game.season}</h2>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      )
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

JSON:
[JSON GET EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eVbI.png)
Later I would like to extract the teams from the JSON file. For example: response.teams.home.name

Thank you in advance for your attention! :)
If there is any information missing, please let me know.

Many greetings and thanks

Comment: First of all , don't share your private API key on public. Your initial state is empty and you can make a condition like {games && games.map(xxx)}.

Comment: And i see "parameters" property is an object so you can't use map function there. What if you do setGames(data.response) then you can use map function to turn your state into a list.

Comment: Why not upgrade to React 17+ and utilize function components? You are already using the `useState` hook.

Comment: Have now tried it with the above condition and unfortunately it did not work either. But instead a new error message: TypeError: games.map is not a function

Also deleted the "parameters" and tried it with setGames(data.response). Also without success.

Comment: See [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70357471/1762224) below. You can run the snippet directly. As long as you supply the API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the structure of your data, if you want to map over it appropriately.

**Note:** Do not use an array index for the `key` of an item in a mapping. Each game contains a `fixture` object with an `id`.

```js
const API_KEY = prompt('Supply the API key'); // Provide the key first!

const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const apiHost = 'v3.football.api-sports.io';
const apiUrl = `https://${apiHost}/fixtures`;
const apiKey = API_KEY;

const toParamString = (obj) => new URLSearchParams(obj).toString();

const getGames = ({ season, league, date }) => {
  const url = `${apiUrl}?${toParamString({ season, league, date })}`;
  return fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'v3.football.api-sports.io',
        'x-apisports-key': apiKey,
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.response);
};

const Score = (props) => {
  const { game: { fixture: { date }, score: { fulltime }, teams } } = props;
  
  return (
    <div className="score">
      <div className="score-date">{new Date(date).toLocaleString()}</div>
      <div className="score-grid">
        <div>{teams.home.name}</div>
        <div>{teams.away.name}</div>
        <div>{fulltime.home}</div>
        <div>{fulltime.away}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App  = () => {
  const [games, setGames] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getGames({
      season: 2021,
      league: 78,
      date: '2021-12-04'
    }).then(data => setGames(data));
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Games</h1>
      <div className="games">
        {games.map((game) => {
          const { fixture: { id } } = game;
          return (
            <Score key={id} game={game} />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

#react-app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.score {
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0.667em;
  padding: 0.33em;
}

.score-date {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.score-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.score-grid div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-app"></div>
```

Comment: It works! :) Thank you very much for your efforts to put the code so detailed online! This helps immensely!
Will now study the code to understand how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 function App() {
      const [games, setGames] = useState({});
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getGames();
    
        async function getGames() {
          const response = await fetch(
            "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?season=2021&league=78&date=2021-12-04",
            {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
                "x-apisports-key": "3914b827d25c9a793d6af1ec9c312d55",
              },
            }
          );
    
          const data = await response.json();
          setGames(data.parameters);
        }
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Games</h1>
          <div className="games">
            {Object.keys(games).length > 0 && games.map((game, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <h2>{game.season}</h2>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          )
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: 'parameters ' key is an object so you can't map through it. And please add more information to explain what you did fix.

Comment: Unfortunately your idea has also not worked :/
Error message now: TypeError: games.map is not a function

Comment: I have not made any major changes always. Always tried and failed :D
Have tried for example step by step to map the "games" to get deeper and deeper in. However, then always came the error message. 
Then I tried it without .map() and got the following error message:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
From this I understood again that I have to map "games" via .map().
And since then I've just been going around in circles and can't find any more solutions.